# Get the name of a chosen item in QListWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

While working on an app for scientific purposes, I struggled to add items to QListWidget. I did not find any documentation for PyQt5, so decided to ask here. I am not directly sure if the usage of QListWidget is right, so correct me if I'm wrong.

UPD: Next iteration.

What I have done.

1. I got names and paths of a folder's content into an array. Where in the first column I get names of files and in second theirs paths.

   ```
   sample_directory = []

   sample_files = []

   for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Samples'):
       sample_files.extend(filenames)
       break

   paths = []    

   for i in range(len(sample_files)):
       path = os.path.realpath(sample_files[i])
       paths.append(path)


   sample_directory.append(sample_files)
   sample_directory.append(paths)
   ```

> [['exmpl1.xlsx', 'exmpl2.xlsx'], ['/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science
>   comput/Application/exmpl1.xlsx', '/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science
>   comput/Application/exmpl2.xlsx']]

2. Next, I added the first column of `sample_directory` to QListWidget `self.sampleChoose_list.addItems(sample_directory[0])`

What I need now.

On button click, when file is chosen, the path to the file should be given to the process function. How can I do it? How can I call the chosen file?

Process function is the function, that gets the path of chosen item, reads it with `pandas.read_excel(sample_directory[0][0])` and makes some work with array. Something like:

```
def process(self):
    sample = pd.read_excel(path_of_a_chosen_file)
    #Where path_of_a_chosen_file is sample_directory[1][i] and i - index of chosen file
    list_of_index = []
    for i in range(len(sample.columns)):
        sample2 = sample.iloc[:, lambda sample: [i]]
        sample2 = sample2.columns[0]
        list_of_index.append(sample2)
    list_of_index
return self.list_of_index
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to explain better what you want to do and what you've done. A Qlistview should works fine to construct a list of items. However a treeview could also be nice to display folder content if there are nested folders.

Comment: @Yohboy updated with some more info. Maybe something more is needed?

Comment: @Graygood You have several tasks to perform, the first task is to read a folder and get the name of the file and the path, the second is to iterate in a loop and add one by one using the addItem method that you know.

Comment: @eyllanesc did this. Could you give me some next instructions, please?

Comment: What is a process function? If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], you are assuming that we know what you know and it is not, we are not in your brain.

Comment: @eyllanesc updated with minimal example and changed the question

Comment: According to what you indicate in your question you have a button, which is pressed, then which of the items should get the name.

Comment: @eyllanesc I choose the item, then press the button that runs process function. When I press this button, the path to the chosen file should be given to this func. The problem is I could not find code examples, that show how to get the name of a selected item. The other problem is, I do not know how to connect list items with it's paths without 'if' statements. Should I use dictionaries?

Comment: How do you choose an item? or rather, how do you want to choose an item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected row from the QListWidget, use `self.sampleChoose_list.selectedIndexes()[0].row()` (the `[0]` here will give you only the first row if multiple are selected).  You can use this index to get the path that corresponds to the selected file name and you can call this from your `process` function.

```
def process(self):
    index = self.sampleChoose_list.selectedIndexes()[0].row()
    path_of_a_chosen_file = self.sample_directory[1][index]
    sample = pd.read_excel(path_of_a_chosensen_file)
```

For this solution to work, you will have to make `sample_directory` a class variable by adding `self.` in front so that it can be accessed from the class's method.